# I am writing my own basic operating system, in NASM 16 bits, and it keeps printing a string that I didn't tell it to

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bios

I have written a terminal style os but the next sector doesn't load and I can't seem to find why a string I never told it to print is printing.

```
[bits 16]           ; tell assembler that working in real mode(16 bit mode)
[org 0x7c00]        ; organize from 0x7C00 memory location where BIOS will load us
%define cr 0xd
%define lf 0xa

start:              ; start label from where our code starts


    xor ax,ax           ; set ax register to 0
    mov ds,ax           ; set data segment(ds) to 0
    mov es,ax           ; set extra segment(es) to 0
    mov bx,0x8000
    ;clear screen
    mov ah, 00h
    mov al, 2
    int 10h
    ;reset cursor
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00h
    mov dh, 00h
    mov dl, 00h
    int 10h
    ;start kernl
    mov si, intro_os
    call print_str ;here is where I call the defined print function, it should move straight to pt2 of it
    ;Functions here
    print_str:
    mov ah, 0xE
    .repeat:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 10h
    jmp .repeat
    .done:
    ret
    read_inp:
    .repeat:
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h
    cmp al, 0x1c
    je .done
    mov bx, [input_idx]
    mov [input+bx], al
    inc byte [input_idx]
    mov ah, 0xE
    int 10h
    jmp .repeat
    .done:
    mov byte [input_idx], 0
    ret
    ;end functions
    ;vars and strings
    intro_os db 'ProtOS VERSION:ALPHA-001, written by Julian Ratcliffe.',cr,lf,0
    loading db 'Please wait, we are loading the operating system...',cr,lf,0 ;this is being printed unintentionally
    kern_mn db cr,lf,'<ProtOS_V_A001>---$ ',0
    input times 100 db 0
    input_idx db 0
    ;end vars and strings
    ; load second sector into memory
    mov ah, 0x02                    ; load second stage to memory
    mov al, 1                       ; numbers of sectors to read into memory
    mov dl, 0x80                    ; sector read from fixed/usb disk
    mov ch, 0                       ; cylinder number
    mov dh, 0                       ; head number
    mov cl, 2                       ; sector number
    mov bx, _OS_Stage_2             ; load into es:bx segment :offset of buffer
    int 0x13                        ; disk I/O interrupt

    jmp _OS_Stage_2                 ; jump to second stage



    ; boot loader magic number
    times ((0x200 - 2) - ($ - $$)) db 0x00     ;set 512 bytes for boot sector which are necessary
    dw 0xAA55                                  ; boot signature 0xAA & 0x55







_OS_Stage_2:
    ;part two of OS (it never reaches this)
    mov ah, 00h
    mov al, 02h
    int 10h
    
    mov si, intro_os
    call print_str
    mov si, kern_mn
    call print_str
    call read_inp
    ; add how much memory we need
    times (1024 - ($-$$)) db 0x00
```

It calls the print function to print the intro_os string, but then it somehow ends up printing out the loading string, and all movement through the code halts, I did try to see what it was by putting cli and hlt below the calling of the printing function, that shows that it (the glitch) is in either the functions section or the vars section.
Please help me see anything I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does execution continue after the first `call print_str` returns?

Comment: @ecm It's supposed to move to loading the second sector into memory

Comment: And how is it supposed to do that, to know what you want it to do next?

Comment: I don't understand, please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Your " ;Functions here" comment is not used by the assembler in any way, it does not indicate that the control flow should skip around the functions and the data. After your first `call` instruction returned your control flow will fall through and execute `print_str` again.

Comment: _facepalm_ I'm still confused as to why it decided of all strings, to print the 'loading' string.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: Your `si` register after the first run through `print_str` is left pointing behind the first message, which is exactly where your second message starts. That's why it displays that. To fix it, move the entire code part starting with the comment "; load second sector into memory" to place it directly behind `call print_str`.

Comment: now the loading into sector two is broken.

Comment: "Broken" how? Also you may want to open a new question for that if you fixed your string printing problem.

Answer (score 1):

ecm helped me figure out the string printing error, just move the sector loading code behind the `call print_str`